# How to run unix utility with NSTask and input data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, input, terminal, nstask

I run zip utility from my app to create archive. Code similar to the following:

```
NSString *toolPath = @"/usr/bin/zip";
NSTask *task = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
[task setLaunchPath:toolPath];
[task setArguments:arguments];
[task launch];
```

, where arguments it is typically string with paths to files. However, when need to create a password protected archive (with the -e argument), password is entered after the launch, and two times. In terminal it looks like this:

```
$ zip -e archive.zip file_to_archive.txt
Enter password:
Verify password:
```

How do I make enter a password in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `man zip`:

```
   -P password
   --password password
          Use password to encrypt zipfile entries (if any).  THIS IS INSE-
          CURE!   Many  multi-user  operating systems provide ways for any
          user to see the current command line of any other user; even  on
          stand-alone  systems  there  is  always  the threat of over-the-
          shoulder peeking.  Storing the plaintext password as part  of  a
          command  line  in  an  automated script is even worse.  Whenever
          possible, use the non-echoing, interactive prompt to enter pass-
          words.   (And  where  security  is  truly  important, use strong
          encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively
          weak standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.)
```

You can resolve the problem by using the -P parameter, I think you don't need so much security.